# ¿Cómo puedo reutilizar esta función?

Tags: angular, typescript, funciones, img

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es poder reutlizar mi código que muestra un preview de una imagen que un usuario sube, pero quiero que pueda hacer lo mismo en diferentes lados y mostrando otra imagen que suba. Muestro mi función, gracias.

```
toBase64(){
  let _ = this;
  var preview = document.querySelector('.preview');
  var file   = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  };

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
  console.log(file);
}

<input type="file" (change)="toBase64()">
<img class="preview" scr="" alt="">
<img  src="" alt="">`
```

Answer (score 0):

Dando por echo que tu función no tiene errores, y lo que tu buscas es reutilizar tu función y mandarla a llamarla en diferentes partes de tu aplicación para no reescribir código, haz lo siguiente:

Crea un `Service`, en tu función modifiqué los parámetros de entrada, pasando el `id` del elemento `img` y del `button` para poder jalar los datos del botón file e incrustar la imagen.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UtilService {

  constructor() { }
    public toBase64 = (_idImg: string, _idButton): void => {
        let preview = document.querySelector('#'+_idImg);
        let file = document.querySelector('#'+_idButton).files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        };
        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else { 
            preview.src = ""; 
        } 
        console.log(file);
    }
}
```

No olvides importar tu servicio en el módulo correspondiente y agregar este  en `Providers`

```
import { UtilService } from './util.service';

providers: [UtilService]
```

Importar e inyectar tu servicio en el constructor de tu componente donde lo vallas a utilizar.

```
import { UtilService } from './util.service';

constructor(_util: UtilService)
```

Tu vista queda de la siguiente manera:

```
  <input type="file" id="btn1" (change)="_util.toBase64('img1','btn1')">
    <img class="preview" id="img1" scr="" alt="">

   <input type="file" id="btn2" (change)="_util.toBase64('img2','btn2')">
    <img class="preview" id="img2" scr="" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como la tienes escrita ahora mismo, es un método de un componente. Esto hace que tengas dependencias externas.

Por otro lado, trabajando con Angular generalmente no necesitas buscar los elementos que forman parte de tu componente para asignarles nada, deberían ser ellos los que busquen sus asignaciones.

Tomando estas ideas en cuenta puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Generaliza la función, sacándola de los componentes: Vas a recibir un fichero de imagen, te debería dar igual si viene de un input o de otro sitio:

  ```
  function imgToBase64(File file, HTMLImageElement img) {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    if (file) {
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        img.src = reader.result;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
  ```
- Ponla en un fichero aparte y expórtala, para que cualquier componente pueda usarla. Podrías tener un fichero utils.ts con una lista de funciones que sean de ayuda para cualquier componente.
- En tu componente podrías tener algo como:

  ```
  <input .... (change)="loadFile($event)" />
  <img #myImg src=''/>
  ```

  y algo como:

  ```
  import {imgToBase64} from '<path>/utils';

  class MiComponente {

    @ViewChild('myImg') myImg: ElementRef;




    constructor(....) { };

    loadFile(event) {
      const files = Array.from(event.target.files as FileList);
      imgToBase64(files[0],myImg.nativeElement);

    }
  }
  ```

**Nota**: he escrito el código aquí directamente y es posible que haya que tocarlo para que compile y funcione correctamente, pero creo que la idea está clara